# PHP PDOStatement prepare and bindValue methods

Tags: php, prepare, pdo

why doesn't below code work ?

```
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=_test;host=localhost','root', '');
 $select=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE th=:name");
 $select->bindValue(":name","1");
 print_r($select);
```

when i print $select it results :

```
 PDOStatement Object ( [dbh] => PDO Object ( ) [queryString] => SELECT * FROM test   WHERE th=:name )
```

thanks!

Comment: You should not modify your original code with suggestions from answers as that will invalidate the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add error handling to your database calls, for example by setting up PDO to throw exceptions.

Your current problem is that you don't actually [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) the statement:

```
$select->bindValue(":name","1");
$select->execute();
```

After that you would need to [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) results from the result set to actually see the values in your database:

```
while ($row = $select->fetch()) {
  // do something with the data
}
```

**Edit:** To enable exceptions in PDO (you don't have to catch them just yet, the system will throw unhandled exception errors):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=_test;host=localhost','root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

Comment: @WEBDESIGNER Are you fetching rows and have you added error handling?